# Hiding inner class in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, class, inner-classes, access-control

I'm trying to hide a inner class so the caller is not aware of it. If the caller want, they can get an instance of the inner class by using a public method. But the caller should not be able to directly get the inner class.

Example to show what I want:

```
class A {
    static func getSettings() -> Settings {
        return Settings()
    }
    class Settings {
        func turnOnSomeThing() {
            
        }
    }
}
 
class test {
    func testFunc() {
        A.getSettings().turnOnSomeThing() // correct way of calling
        A.Settings().turnOnSomeThing() // should not be possible
    }
}
```

Is this possbile in Swift?

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is a singleton

Comment: `class Settings {` `private init() {}` `static let shared = Settings()` `func turnOnSomeThing() {` `print(#function)` `}`
`}`
 
`class test {`
    `func testFunc() {`
        `Settings.shared.turnOnSomeThing()` // ok        `Settings().turnOnSomeThing()` // error
   `}`
`}`

Comment: I want the instance to come from the outer class getter method so i can perform checks and make sure the call will succed before returning the instance of the inner class.

Comment: You can customize the shared  instance. If you don’t provide a practical example it will be difficult to help https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why do both calls work in the test caller?

Both currently work because:

- The first case, `A.getSettings()...` is a classic getter that returns an object.  I'm just puzzled with the fact that a new `Settings` is constructed each time,  but this is perfectly legit.
- The second case, `A.Settings()....` invokes the constructor of `Settings` to create an anonymous object, and invokes some methods on it. It's ok, because the inner class is public, but it's weird.

### Can you make the inner class private?

You could make an inner class private to avoid it being accessed from the outside world:

- This would work perfectly well for an private helper class totally invisible to the outside world.
- For `Settings` this is not possible,  because `getSettings()` returns objects of this class to the outside world, and this makes only sense if the outside world knows the class to deal with it.

Exemple:

```
class A {
    static func getSettings() -> Settings {   // ERROR if Settings would be private 
        let helper = Helper() // purely internal use: Helper can be private :-)
        helper.demo()
        return Settings()
    }
    class Settings {              // making private is not possible (see above)
        func turnOnSomeThing() {
            print ("On")
        }
    }
    private class Helper {        // Cannot be used outside
       func demo() {
            print ("Demo")
        }
    }
}
```

### But how to do with Settings?

If you want to return `Settings` objects to the wild outside world you need to keep that class public.  However,  if you want to avoid that the outside world misues the inner class and avoid objects to be created from the outside wolrd,  you can use access control on the constructor:

```
class A {
    static func getSettings() -> Settings {
        ...
    }
    class Settings {
        fileprivate init() {  /// <===  ACCESS CONTROL internal or fileprivate 
        }
        func turnOnSomeThing() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This prevents the calls of the form `A.Settings()...`,  but only according to swift [access control](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html):  with `internal` you can still call the constructor from another file of the same module;  with `fileprivate` the constructor can only be called from within the source file in which you've defined your external class.

This technique of making the constructor inaccessible while keeping the class usable is frequently used for classes which instances shall only be created via a factory.